# Change background image page header overlay for each category

Tags: categories, images, custom-background

this is my site: http://styleofchamp.com/ and I'm trying to change the background image page header overlay for each category. I have been looking at many forums but I didn't get with the correct answer.

For example: on this page http://styleofchamp.com/category/futbol/ it should show a different background image page header overlay than this one: http://styleofchamp.com/category/tenis/

If anybody could help me with this I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably the easiest method.

If you inspect the `<body>` tag by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> in your browser you will see it has a different class for each category.  You can use this to target your header element for each specific category.

For example, this will change the image for category 6.

```
body.category-6 .page-header {
    background-image: url( http://styleofchamp.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/sabri-tuzcu-190600-unsplash-1.jpg ) !important;
}
```

Note: You can upload images via the file uploader and then just replace the correct path for the background-image URL.

CSS changes can be added to Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS

Comment: Thank you so much!! that's work perfectly.

Comment: One more question, how can edit the position of the image? Like top-center, top-right, etc.

Comment: You can use CSS background-position, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position